# CNTK on Jupyter notebook kernal not working

Tags: azure, ipython, jupyter, cntk, azure-dsvm

I am trying to get Jupyter Notebook to work with my Azure data Science VM and the kernel in not working. I installes CNTK using the shellbash and it works well from the command like. However when I pull it up using Anaconda or with the command: "jupyter notebook" I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-               packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 503, in wrapper
result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-   packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1015, in run
value = future.result()
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 237, in result
raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1021, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 75, in post
type=mtype))
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1015, in run
value = future.result()
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 237, in result
raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1021, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 79, in   create_session
kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1015, in run
value = future.result()
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 237, in result
raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1021, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 92, in   start_kernel_for_session
self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1015, in run
value = future.result()
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 237, in result
raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 285, in wrapper
yielded = next(result)
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 87, in start_kernel
super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 243, in start_kernel
**kw)
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 189, in _launch_kernel
return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 123, in launch_kernel
proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Any advice on how to get the python kernel to work with CNTK in the notebook?

Answer (score 2):

I opened up the terminal to the CNTK-py35 directory and entered the following code and the kernel started working got it working:

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5
activate py35
conda install notebook ipykernel
ipython kernel install --user --name=python3.5
```

Then I opened jupyter notebook from inside Anaconda and ran

```
import CNTK
```

Comment: Thanks Levi for sharing your solution

Answer (score 0):

Need a bit more information to give you meaningful advice, as I cannot see it from the screen dump.

- Are you able to activate CNTK-py35 environment
- If you are able to activate the environment, could you please start the python kernel from within the activated environment
- If you are successful with that from within the python shell are you able to run `import CNTK`
- If that works, that means your CNTK installation is good.

Now you can go the command prompt, from within the activate environment can you try starting the jupyter notebook environment.

You can find more information along these lines for the python setup, at this link: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Setup-Windows-Python

Comment: Yes the installation of CNTK is fine. It works in ipython and in the command line. But not in jupyer notebook which when I open from the CNTK-py36 environment I get kernal error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified